# Dicas de segurança projeto PHP

Tags: php

Estou em um projeto de um site, nele fiz tratamento de dados usando PDO e assim achei que estava tudo ok.

Porem recentemente fiz um teste com acunetix e o resultado de error foi nivel 4, XSS foi o mais acusado.

Então pensando nisso, fiz varias pesquisas e comecei a filtrar todos os dados, GET, POST, SERVER.

**Exemplo**

```
E Seguro desta forma? 

$method_req = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$req_referer = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_REFERER', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if($method_req == 'POST'){
header('Location: '.$req_referer);
}

$url_reqhost = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$url_req_url = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$URL_ATUAL = "https://".$url_reqhost.$url_req_url;

$filtrar_estilo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'estilo', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

**Resumindo oque ja fiz para segurança:**

- Uso de PDO
- Limitação de caracteres .htaccess ('," etc, passa apenas letras e numero)
- Bloqueio ao acesso direto dos .php
- Filtro de dados POST/GET/SERVER

**Oque necessito**

- O que mais preciso no momento e de dicas e ideias para complementar meu código, principalmente nessa questão de segurança get/post.
- E Necessário filtrar session?
- Quais o melhor filtro para validar os dados FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING? (o projeto nunca irá receber aspas ou algo do tipo, apenas letras e numeros)

Comment: Tudo está no tema central do post (filtrar informações)

Comment: cara eu alem disso q vc fez eu faço um str_replace e tiro caracteres indesejados. quando tenho um fileupload valido o conteudo do arquivo para que so possa ser feito upload de imagens ou pdf